# On theorem 15.4 of Matsumura

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Matsumura is proving that $\dim A[X]=\dim A+1$. Using a theorem proved previously he proves that if $P$ is a prime ideal of $A[X]$ and $p=P\cap A$ then $\mathrm{ht}\;P=\mathrm{ht}\;p+1$, but it doesn't seem obvious to me that from this last equality we get $\dim A[X]=\dim A+1$, could you explain to me how to get to the equality that I want to prove?

Comment: *Which* Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory* or *Commutative Algebra*?

Comment: @ZevChonoles *Commutative Ring Theory*

Comment: ht $P =$ ht $p + 1$ should be ht $P \le$ ht $p + 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $B = A[X]$.
Let dim $A = n$.
If $p$ is a prime ideal of $A$, then $pB + XB$ is a prime ideal of $B$.
Hence dim $B \ge n + 1$.
Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $B$.
Let $p = A \cap P$.
Since ht $P \le$ ht $p + 1$, ht $P \le n + 1$.
Hence dim $B \le n + 1$